# C++ Exercise in Parsing with Classes, getline, and stringstream

Tags: c++, parsing, getline, stringstream

I've been really struggling to figure out how to use getline and stringstream together to parse a file. If someone could help explain I'd be extremely grateful. EXTREMELY.

I'm really trying to build the function ReadFile, which is a function that reads in a filename comprised of "name, salary" format text for 50 names and salaries. I want to separate it into the arrays named: names[] salary[].

What I have so far is below, I think my class structure is alright according to the prompt, but could someone help me in reading the file into the separate arrays properly? Thank you!

```
class Players {

    public:
        //Initialize
        float salaries[50];
        string names[50];

        Players(){
            for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            float salaries[i]={-1.0};
            string names[i]= {""} ; }
        }

        void ReadFile(string filename) {
            ifstream file;
            file.open(filename);

            string line;
            int index=0;
            while (getline(file, line)) {
                stringstream ss(line);
                getline(ss, names[index], ',');
                getline(ss, salaries[index]);

                index ++
                string names;
                float salaries;

                ss >> names >> salaries >> ',';           
            }
        }

    float MaxSalary() {

    }

    string MaxSalaryName() {

    }
};
```

Comment: Please remove the prompt and refocus your question on the specific part in your code example you are having trouble with.

Comment: No problem! Done. Sorry I though the prompt might help clear confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should not compile. In the future please ensure your code examples compile without modification, and include all your #includes.

A few things about your `ReadFile` function:

- You are redefining your variables `names` and `salaries`. You probably don't want that.
- `index ++` should be `index++;`.
- `ifstream::open` takes a C string, so you need to pass in `filename.c_str()`.
- Your first `getline` is fine, but your second is attempting to copy a string directly into a float. You need to explicitly do the type conversion. One way is to create a temporary string variable, pass it to `getline`, then use `std::stof` to convert that string into a float. This requires C++11. If you can't use C++11, you could use `strtof` from `<cstdilib>`.
- Not sure what the `ss >> ...` is meant to achieve, but you probably don't want it. If you want to print your results, you want something like `cout << names[index] << ": " << salaries[index] << "\n";`

A few things about your `Players()` constructor:

- You are redefining your member variables because you include types in front of the variable names. Remove the types.
- The default string constructor creates an empty string, so there is no need to initialize it with an empty string.
- You can safely drop the `{}` around the initialization values.

Most of these problems could have been caught by looking at compiler errors and then looking up the appropriate C++ documentation. That said, I know C++ isn't the easiest language to get started in and it helps allot to have pointers early on. Keep at it and you will get it!

Comment: Thank you so for these! I've implemented them all. I don't want to print out the names[index] or salary[index], but rather have the values from the file stored in those arrays correctly. I was told by a tutor the ss >> names >> salaries was a correct structure but I really don't understand what it's doing. I just want the filname file parse into those two arrays.

Comment: You already accomplished reading the values into the arrays with the `getline` functions. You can check by printing out the values of the variables and ensuring they match the expected values.

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to get it to print out but the error I find I don't quite understand. prog.cpp: In member function 'void Players::ReadFile(std::__cxx11::string)':
prog.cpp:32:40: error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::stringstream&, float&)'
             getline(ss, salaries[index]);

Comment: Ahh I think I understand. I'll keep tweaking it.

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark.